# Redirect Non-Logged In Users to Specific Page based on Page Template

Tags: wp-redirect

I would like to redirect all non-logged in users to a specific page if they are directly trying to access:

- Any category archive
- Any tag archive
- Any single post

I'm trying to use this code in child theme's `functions.php`, but it is not working.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );
function redirect_to_specific_page() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'single-post' ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( '/', 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an updated version of the code that successfully redirects users who are not logged in to a specific page when they try and view a tag or category archive or a singular post.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_redirect_to_specific_page' );
function wpse_redirect_to_specific_page() {
    // Bail if the user is logged in.
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Redirect to a special page if the user is trying to access
    // a category or tag archive or a single post.
    if ( is_category() || is_tag() || is_singular( 'post' ) ) {

        // Set the ID of the page to redirect to.
        // Change the ID to the desired page to redirect to.
        $redirect_to_page_id = 1086;

        wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( $redirect_to_page_id ), 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
```

**Handling custom taxonomies**

If you'd like to redirect custom taxonomy archive pages, you could add [`is_tax()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/) to the conditional statement that wraps the redirect code.

**Handling custom post types**

If you'd like to do the same for all post type singular pages, you could use [`is_singular()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/) without passing the `post` parameter, or for specific post types, pass an array of post type names.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanx! But, as a relative newbie on this stuff, I am curious how I would go about defining specific cats and tags. I tried to add them in this way, but it didnt work. What am I doing wrong?      if ( is_category('test','test-2')

Comment: Glad to hear! Your'e on the right track, but pass multiple [category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/) or [tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tag/) slugs as an array, e.g. `is_category( array( 'test', 'test-2'  ) )`.